# How to hide the tr using data attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: This is the table row that has a data attribute. if the data attribute is 2020-09-15 the table row are hiding.]

This is my jquery function to hide table row, in there I put the data attribute expiry

```js
     $("tr.with-expiry").each(function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var tr_date = $(this).data('expiry');
            tr_date = new Date(today);
            if (today.getTime() > tr_date.getTime()) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 1</td></tr>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 2</td></tr>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-08-01" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 3</td></tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: I see in the comments below some confusion over why our answers are not hiding `2020-09-15` - this is because your code is hiding dates **before** today, so our answers are doing that too. If you want it to work differently then you just need to change the date comparison you are using. Or you can [edit] your question to let us know what you want to do and we can help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question still needs alot more clarity to what was posted initially - OP is getting the correct answer but keeps the changing question with different requirements.

Comment: Hi @JohnMark Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below one of the answers or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional assistance can be provided. That will help us out. *(Also remember that upvoting is encouraged in order to reward answers that were particularly informative - and it is possible to also upvote the answer that you checkmark.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're very close, you just are getting the `Date()` for your date-expiry incorrectly

```
tr_datetime = new Date(tr_date);
```

You were just overwriting it with today's date. The rest of the code then works as expected.

**Date Comparison**: To hide dates...

- ...Before today: `if (today_datetime > tr_datetime.getTime())`
- ...Up to today: `if (today_datetime >= tr_datetime.getTime())`  (i.e. including today)
- ...After today: `if (today_datetime < tr_datetime.getTime())`
- ...Today or later: `if (today_datetime <= tr_datetime.getTime())`

**Adjust Today's Date by 1 Week**:

- One week from today: `today_datetime + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`
- One week ago: `today_datetime - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

**Other Notes:** FYI, you don't need to get `today = new Date();` etc. every time - just get it once outside the loop.

**Working Snippet:**

```js
var today = new Date();
var today_datetime = today.getTime();

$("tr.with-expiry").each(function() {
    tr_datetime = new Date($(this).data('expiry'));
    if (today_datetime > tr_datetime.getTime()) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});

var week_from_today = today_datetime + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
$("tr.expiry-next-week").each(function() {
    tr_datetime = new Date($(this).data('expiry'));
    if (week_from_today > tr_datetime.getTime()) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Show rows with dates after today</strong></p>
<table>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-01" class="with-expiry"><td>2020-09-01</td></tr>  
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-09" class="with-expiry"><td>2020-09-09</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-10" class="with-expiry"><td>2020-09-10</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-16" class="with-expiry"><td>2020-09-16</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-17" class="with-expiry"><td>2020-09-17</td></tr>
</table>
<p><strong>Show rows with dates later than 1 week from today</strong></p>
<table>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-01" class="expiry-next-week"><td>2020-09-01</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-09" class="expiry-next-week"><td>2020-09-09</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-10" class="expiry-next-week"><td>2020-09-10</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-16" class="expiry-next-week"><td>2020-09-16</td></tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-17" class="expiry-next-week"><td>2020-09-17</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: They are all test1.

Comment: @FluffyKitten not hiding in my output

Comment: @FluffyKitten this expiration, for example, I add data today in my server-side so it will become the expiration is `2020-09-16`  this data will hiding in `tr`.

Comment: @FluffyKitten after 1 week they will hiding example I add data today `2020-09-09` 1 week after `2020-09-16` this date will hiding after 1 week.

Comment: @FluffyKitten 1 week after i want to hide the `tr`. Example today I add data in my backend the expiration is 2020-09-16 and then tomorrow I add again 1 week after the expiration is 2020-09-17,

Comment: @JohnMark That's how the code is working... `2020-09-01` and `2020-09-09` are being hidden. `2020-09-15` would have been added yesterday and expires next week on 15th, so it is not being hidden yet - it will be hidden next week. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes not like that. For example today I add data from `2020-09-09` to `2020-09-16`, this date `2020-09-16`  1week after will hide, Example again I will add data on `2020-09-11` to `2020-09-18`,  this date `2020-09-18` 1week after will hide.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really clear it up! This works the same way as the code in your question. You are hiding it when it reaches the date shown in data-expiry (e.g. data-enquiry =`2020-09-09` so it is hidden today). Is your code wrong? Can you explain when do you want to hide the date in `data-expiry`? That's all we need to know. e.g, if data-expiry = `2020-09-09`, hide it on 16/9/2020?

Comment: @FluffyKitten i want to hide after 1week, not today. like this 16/9/2020 this I want to hide.

Comment: @JohnMark That wasn't mentioned at all in your question! We can only work based on what you gave us, which was the code hiding anything with today's date. I'll look at updating my answer, but for future reference please remember that changing  your question after it is answered is actually against the site guidelines :) Make sure you include your *full* question when you post it!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// `a` and `b` are `Date` instances
const isAfter = (a, b) => a.getTime() > b.getTime();

// Example - Is '2020-09-10' after today?
const result = isAfter(new Date('2020-09-10'), new Date());  

// Result
console.log(result)
```

```js
// `a` and `b` are `Date` instances
const isAfter = (a, b) => a.getTime() > b.getTime()
const todayDate = new Date()
const todayString = todayDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10)

$("tr.with-expiry").each(function() {
  var tr_date_val = $(this).data('expiry')

  // if the row's data-expiry attribute is after today
  if (isAfter(new Date(tr_date_val), todayDate)) {
    $(this).css({background: 'red'})
    console.log(`${tr_date_val} is after ${todayString} so hide`)
    //$(this).hide()
  } else {
    console.log(`${tr_date_val} is not after ${todayString} so show`)
    $(this).css({background: 'green'})
    //$(this).show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry">
    <td>2020-09-15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry">
    <td>2020-09-15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-expiry="2020-08-01" class="with-expiry">
    <td>2020-08-01</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: whye the 2020-09-15 not hiding ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
     $("tr.with-expiry").each(function() {
            var today = new Date();

            var data_expiry = $(this).attr('data-expiry');
            var tr_date = new Date(data_expiry);

            if (today.getTime() > tr_date.getTime()) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 1</td></tr>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-09-15" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 2</td></tr>
     <tr data-expiry="2020-08-01" class="with-expiry"><td>stuff 3</td></tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: the data attribute is random date example the expiry is 2020-09-12, 2020-09-13, 2020-10-01, 2020-10-05, 2020-10-09, 2020-11-01 this date I want to hide if meet the date today.

Comment: @JohnMark You want `< than today`, `<= than today`, `= to today`, `>= than today` or `> than today` to be hidden?

Comment: Yes, because the data attribute is not the same date. The attribute is coming from the server side  <tr data-expiry="<?= $item->date_expire ?>" class="with-expiry"> this one.

Comment: @JohnMark What is the condition for hidding the line? Tell me 1 of these condition : `< than today`, `<= than today`, `= to today`, `>= than today`, `> than today` or `!= to today`.  Which one is it?

Comment: I'm using this `>`, `>=` is not hiding.

Comment: this expiration, for example, I add data today in my server-side so it will become the expiration is `2020-09-16 ` this data will hiding in `tr`.

Comment: I'm sorry, your english is very poor and I don't understand what you are trying to say.